# Error building mono in scratchbox

Tags: mono, arm, embedded-linux

I tried to compile mono for arm in scratchbox on Ubuntu 11.10. But when I make install I got an error message.

```
[sbox-ARMEL:~] ./configure --enable-minimal=profiler,debug,logging,soft_debug --with-tls=--with-tls=__thread --with-monotouch=no --without-mcs-docs --disable-mono-debugger CFLAGS=-DARM_FPU_NONE --disable-mcs-build
[sbox-ARMEL:~] make
[sbox-ARMEL:~] make install
```

I get this error:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/johannes/mono-2.10.2/mono/mini'
CC  genmdesc-genmdesc.o
In file included from mini.h:39,
                 from genmdesc.c:9:
mini-unwind.h:106: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'mgreg_t'
mini-unwind.h:107: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'mgreg_t'
In file included from genmdesc.c:9:
mini.h:741: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'mgreg_t'
In file included from genmdesc.c:9:
mini.h:1843: error: expected ')' before '*' token
mini.h:1848: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'mgreg_t'
mini.h:1923: error: expected ')' before '*' token
mini.h:1924: error: expected ')' before '*' token
mini.h:1925: error: expected ')' before '*' token
mini.h:1926: error: expected ')' before '*' token
mini.h:1928: error: expected ')' before '*' token
mini.h:1930: error: expected ')' before '*' token
mini.h:1931: error: expected ')' before '*' token
mini.h:1932: error: expected ')' before '*' token
mini.h:1933: error: expected ')' before '*' token
mini.h:2061: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'mgreg_t'
mini.h:2084: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'mgreg_t'
mini.h:2092: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'mgreg_t'
mini.h:2093: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'mgreg_t'
mini.h:2094: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'mgreg_t'
mini.h:2096: error: expected ')' before '*' token
mini.h:2100: error: expected ')' before '*' token
mini.h:2101: error: expected ')' before '*' token
mini.h:2105: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'mgreg_t'
mini.h:2138: error: expected ')' before '*' token
mini.h:2148: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'mgreg_t'
make[2]: *** [genmdesc-genmdesc.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/johannes/mono-2.10.2/mono/mini'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/johannes/mono-2.10.2/mono'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Knows anyone this error or what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Get source file from Git because your mini.h and mini-unwind.h file doesn't match the Git one.
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/mini/mini.h